# innerHTML doesnt update permanently using a function. It goes back to original value once function is run

Tags: javascript, html, function, innerhtml

I have only copied a portion of my code here to simplify for readers. I have a navigation bar on a website with an "Add to Cart" button. I also have 15 products, listed with Selectlist array (for customer to chose quantity) and an array of purchase-buttons (15). Each Purchase Button is already linked to the specific product so that whenever a button is fired, I get the quantity value of that specific product. However, when I am running the function in this code, to update the "Add to Cart" in my Navigation bar, the value returns to 0 once the function is run.

```js
 let purchaseButtonArray=  document.querySelectorAll (".purchase-button")
 
 function purchaseButtonIndex ()
    {for (z in purchaseButtonArray)
    if (purchaseButtonArray[z] == this)
    {productPosition = z}
qty = Number(productQtyArray[productPosition].value)

let productNumbers = Number(localStorage.getItem("cartNumbers"))

if (productNumbers){
localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", productNumbers + qty)
updateCart.innerHTML = productNumbers + qty}

else {localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", qty)
updateCart.innerHTML = qty} 
    }


 for (x of purchaseButtonArray) 
x.addEventListener("click",purchaseButtonIndex, false)
```

```html
      <header class="wrapper">
        <nav class="mainnav" id="topLinks">
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Leagues</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Events & Press</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
             <li><button id= "cartbtn"><img src ="D:\coding\CSS\raunaq-project\placeholder-images\shopping-cart.jpg" ></button><span class= "cart">0</span></li>
          </ul>
       </nav>
       
      </header>
```

Comment: Is the code you've shown part of a `form`? If so, the `button` you've added will act as a `submit` button by default, forcing a page reload when clicked, which could be causing the whole page to be rebuilt. If this is the case add `type="button"` to the `button` so that it doesn't submit the form. Also, don't use `.innerHTML` when you aren't working with a string of HTML as `.innerHTML` has security and performance implications. Use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: You also are using a file path for your image on your button rather than an absolute or relative URL, which will be a problem once you run this from a server.